# Why is a file not being uploaded using minIO's putObject?

Tags: java, minio

I am using Minio's JAVA SDK. I managed to copy objects within the same Minio Server. Is there a way to copy the objects from one Minio server to another?

I have tried using the below code:

```
InputStream inputStream = minioClientServer1.getObject(getBucket(), fileName);
minioClientServer2.putObject(getBucket(), fileName, inputStream, (long) inputStream.available(), null, null, contentType);
```

When I try this I get

> java.net.ProtocolException: expected 0 bytes but received 8192

in the second line.
Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `inputStream.available()` with just -1?

Comment: yes sir, I did.

Comment: Well, I don't know a Java solution, but my experience is limited to using s3distcp CLI to copy between standard S3 environments

Comment: when I put -1 I get You must provide the Content-Length HTTP header